# Can anybody recomend a good SEO book?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

Im currently developing a ASP MVC site.

Is there any book out there for ASP MVC SEO or just SEO in general?

Comment: This question would belong on the [Webmasters site](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), if they didn't already have a [similar one](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15104/is-the-art-of-seo-book-dated).

Comment: I wrote this blog article about SEO for ASP.NET sites in general that might be helpful to you: http://programmingincsharp.com/on-site-seo-for-asp-net-applications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEO is not language-specific, since all web languages produce the html/css etc that the web 'runs on'.

However, many others (including myself) will recommend "[The Art of SEO](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-SEO-Theory-Practice-OReilly/dp/0596518862)". It covers all fundamentals of SEO and explains many parts of SEO in-depth.

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous, yes i know its not  server side specific, i was just wondering if a book exists that guides you how to do this easy with patterns, helpers etc to achieve good SEO for a site in ASP MVC.

Comment: Ah right, fair enough. :-) I don't know of any ASP specific books, sorry. I'd just search Amazon in general, there are usually plenty of useful/insightful reviews for each book to help you decide.